# GPS is receiving latitude and longitude although no connection should be available

Tags: android-gps

my problem is that I receive on my Android mobile phone gps coordinates (lat & lng) although there must not be any connection - in the bathroom behind thick walls even calling someone does not work good enough :)

I would like to know how is it possible that I receive lat and lng although no connection should be available.

I will provide parts of my code. Maybe someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        case 2: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap = googleMap;
//      if map is moved around, automatic camera movement is disabled
        mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(this);
        mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    // Get map views
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
            findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    View mapView = mapFragment.getView();
    View location_button =mapView.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton");
    View zoom_in_button = mapView.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapZoomInButton");
    View zoom_layout = (View) zoom_in_button.getParent();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
            location_button.getLayoutParams();
    // position on right bottom
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 255);

//      adjust location button layout params above the zoom layout
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams location_layout = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) location_button.getLayoutParams();
        location_layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
        location_layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, zoom_layout.getId());

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
//      Cross-hair is shown here, right upper corner
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setPadding(0,0,0,90);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: The GPS signals are at a different frequency and in a different direction from your cell phone signal.  They are designed to operate on extremely weak signals, and unlike your cell signal, they do not require 2-way communication.  Did you really think this was a code problem?

Comment: I am not 100% sure whether it could be a code problem.
Firstly, I had the INTERNET permission in my Android MANIFEST as well, so I thought it could be related to that, too?
Is there a way to see how good or bad the signal is and according to that doing my distance calculation?

Comment: GPS is an entirely separate subsystem, unrelated to cell voice and data and unrelated to Internet permissions.   There are a number of Android tools to show you the GPS status.  I use one called "GPS Status".